# Using different redis stores for session and caching in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, ruby-on-rails-5

I am a newbie to Ruby and Rails. I am building a web application using Ruby on Rails 5.2. I have configured it to use the `redis-cache-store` to manage the view caching:

```
config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { driver: :hiredis, namespace: "my-app", compress: true, url: ENV["REDIS_URL"] }
```

And I have configured my session storage as:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cache_store, {
  key: "sid",
  expire_after: 30.minutes
}
```

So here I am using the `:cache_store` as my session store. As far as I understand, this means the entries for the view cache and the session data are stored in the same Redis database.

From what I understand, the `redis-rails` gem is no longer required if using Rails 5.2 as there is a built-in support for redis - https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails#a-quick-note-about-rails-52. Hence, I have not used that gem.

Is there a way to use a different redis store for sessions and different one for view caching?

Or am I trying to do something which is unusual in Rails-land?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To separately configure your session store to use Redis, you'll need to use a gem that provides a Redis session store: either `redis-store` (note `redis-activesupport` is deprecated, but `redis-actionpack` is not), or `redis-session-store`.

You can't configure the session storage separately while using the `:cache_store` session store, because that stores sessions *in the actual cache*... it's not just "cache-like" storage, so it can't override / behave differently from the cache itself.

Storing session contents somewhere other than a cookie is *somewhat* unusual, now that session cookies are encrypted as well as tamper-proof, but it's not rare. If you're going to, Redis is a good choice.

Comment: _Storing session contents somewhere other than a cookie is somewhat unusual, now that session cookies are encrypted as well as tamper-proof_. Does it prevent from [session replay attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) ?

Comment: "Storing session contents somewhere other than a cookie is somewhat unusual, now that session cookies are encrypted as well as tamper-proof, but it's not rare."
It allows you display where a user is logged in as well as invalidate (logout) signed in sessions.