# Store Rails session using Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, redis

The default session store for Rails is `cookie_store`. This makes the session be stored on the client side (correct me if I am wrong).

I want to change this default behavior, so that I can store the sessions into Redis database.
The posts/articles I found on the Internet, suggests setup a caching store to use `redis_cache_store` and then for the session_store, to use `cache_store`.

As I got it, this means that, both caching and sessions will be using the same database (Instance). I don't want that. I want both sessions and cache to use different instances of Redis, so they can be configured accordingly.

I tried to create an initializer file `config/initializers/session_store.rb` with the following content:

```rb
Rails.application.config.session_store :redis_cache_store, key: '_my_app_session'
```

But this does not work. It gives me the following error:

> /application/configuration.rb:324:in `const_get': uninitialized constant ActionDispatch::Session::RedisCacheStore (NameError)

I also found this gem `https://github.com/redis-store/redis-store` but I am not sure how problematic using this gem can be, since Rails already has a built-in Redis cache store (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/31134)

Comment: look into Gemfile/Gemfile.lock to make sure that your redis-cache-store is pickup

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [redis-rails](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails), Rails has a redis cache store out of the box starting with Rails 5.2.

The advise is to use this store for caching (fragment cache).

For sessions, you can still use the session store provided by [redis-actionpack](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-actionpack) which is a part of redis-rails and can be use on its own.

So you should define in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'redis'
gem 'hiredis' # optional
gem 'redis-actionpack'
```

In your environment, define cache and session store (see [Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-rediscachestore) and gem [redis-rails](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails)) for Rail 6 and up (thanks to @daveomcd):

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }
config.session_store :redis_store,
  servers: ["#{ENV['REDIS_URL']}/session"],
  expire_after: 90.minutes,
  key: "_#{Rails.application.class.module_parent_name.downcase}_session",
  secure: true
```

Now your using the cache store of Rails and the session store of redis-rails.
The sessions are namespaced or can be in a different redis instance.

Rails before 6:

before Rails 6 the name of the application (used in key) was derived by

```
Rails.application.class.parent_name.downcase
```

Comment: should now be `Rails.application.class.module_parent_name.downcase`

Answer (score -4):

`redis_cache_store` is a cache store, you cannot directly use it as a session store. You will have to use `redis_cache_store` as your default `cache_store` and then you can use the `cache_store` for your `session_store`. Something like this

In your `config/application.rb` (Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810289/setting-the-cache-store-in-an-initializer/5811913) to know why here)

```
config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, options
```

and then in your `config/initializers/session_store.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.session_store = :cache_store, key: '_app_session_key'
```

There are other options to do this without modifying `cache_store` as well such as [redis-store](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails) and [redis-session-store](https://github.com/roidrage/redis-session-store)

Comment: If you look to the second paragraph, you will see that this is the pattern I want to avoid. I need to have them completely separated. Rigth now I am using redis-store gem. But make not to much sense to me since rails already have a build-in redis implementation

Comment: Using different redis db for session and cache store is not possible for now. More detailed explanation has been provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717865/using-different-redis-stores-for-session-and-caching-in-rails-5